# Cassandra: superslice shows different behavior once records are deleted

Tags: cassandra

I'm performing a superSlice operation on a column family that looks like this:

SuperColumn Family: UserActivity{
    User1{
        Activity1{
            //activity detail columns
        }
        Activity2{
            //activity detail columns
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
}

Test case:
1. Inserted 5 users each with 10 activities in the SCF (super column family).
2. Executed a superSlice query to fetch the top 5 activities for each user.

This works fine in the first attempt. I then deleted all the details.

I immediately re-ran the use case. This time the superSlice returned all 10 activities for each user instead of the 5 as per the slice range specification.

I'm using the Hector API for Cassandra, but I'm seeing the same issue even with a plain thrift call.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Is there any way to get around this?

- Sagar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#range_ghosts

Comment: Thanks for that! 
Is there any way to get around this issue? Even though deletes are rate in my usage scenario it would be good to know this.